# MSFT Graph API Search : Unable to find file by name with space that exists in Sharepoint folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to find in a certain folder (could be inside a sub-folder) in Sharepoint Online.

I'm using MSFT Graph API and see it working for many cases.
I only know the file's name and the possible "root" folder name.

My request is this:

```
{
"requests": [
    {
        "entityTypes": [
            "driveItem",
            "listItem"
        ],
        "query": {
            "queryString": "filename:\"foto 3.jpg\" AND path:https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/teams/MySite/Shared%20Documents/MyRootFolder/*",
            "contentSources": [
                "siteId:mysharepoint.sharepoint.com,<a guid>,<another guid>"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

and I'm sending this as a POST to:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

Don't think the issue is permissions since I have no problem finding some files.

On the query string I already tried:

- without the double quotes wrapping the file name
- without the path
- just the file name

I either get the wrong file in some cases or no file at all. If I don't put the double quotes, in the response I see the "searchTerms" with 2 values: "foto" and "3.jpg".

I know the file exists under the folder I show in path because I go to sharepoint and can see it there.

I can not change the file's names.

Comment: Have you tried to URL-encode the filename value?

Comment: In path, you are specifying teams: https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/teams/xxx . How did you add the file? Through the teams or sharepoint UI? Btw. the same query works fine for me, even the simplest query "queryString": "filename:\"foto 3.jpg\"". Are you able to find any other files from the same sharepoint site?

Comment: Btw: contentSources should be specified only when entityTypes contains externalItem

Comment: Other files Are being found.
I was not aware of the contentSources, I thought it was just a certainty to filter on a specific siteid.
I have copied the files via the browser or the migration tool.

In the meantime I used F12 on sharepoint and noticed the search is sending a query string and query terms. Initial tests seem to show this to work even for this case. If it shows very successful I might create my own response.

Comment: It seems Search is not intended for exact match. Best is exact terms. I can never get just the results that match my string but always will get results that will contain my string... :(

Comment: For exact match, use `=` instead of `:` => `filename=\"foto 3.jpg\"`

Answer (score 0):

Taking into considerations the notes from @user2250152, this is how I manage to do it.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "driveItem", "listItem"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "filename=\"{fileName}\"",
        "queryTemplate": "{searchTerms} (path:\"https://siemens.sharepoint.com/teams/{SourceSiteName}/Shared%20Documents/{SourceFolderName}\" OR ParentLink:\"https://siemens.sharepoint.com/teams/{SourceSiteName}/Shared Documents/{SourceFolderName}*\")"
      },
      \"fields\": [
            \"name\",
            \"id\",
            \"size\"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: Part of my issues were due to indexation of Sharepoint.